# Flattened data frame with hierarchical structure to nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, nested, recursive-datastructures

I have a Pandas data frame that looks like this:

```
Parent_id    Child_id Descr
1            2        Tom
1            3        Mark
1            4        Tony
2            5        Eddy
2            6        Lisa
3            7        Anna
3            8        Maria
7            9        Ali
```

Desired Output is a nested list-dict combo format like this (I need to pass it as JSON to a treeview builder).
I have no clue on how to create this because I don't know the depth of the structure beforehand.

What I know is that id 1 is the parent of all other ids and I don't need to include it. The data frame rows are not necessarily orded by hierarchy level.

```
[{ id: 2,
   descr: Tom,
   nodes: [{id: 5,
            descr: Eddy},
           {id: 6,
            descr: Lisa}
          ]
 },
 { id: 3,
   descr: Mark,
   nodes: [{id: 7,
            descr: Anna,
            nodes: [{id: 9,
                     descr: Ali
                    }]
           },
           {id: 8,
            descr: Maria}
           ]
 { id: 4,
   descr: Tony}
]
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: So Parent_id = 1 is a special case that means the node should be in the top-level list?  Also are you guaranteed that the ids are in ascending order with an id appearing as a Child_id before it appears as a Parent_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
def tree(df, parent=1):
    out = []
    for _, row in df[df.Parent_id == parent].iterrows():
        out.append(
            {
                "id": row["Child_id"],
                "descr": row["Descr"],
                "nodes": tree(df, parent=row["Child_id"]),
            }
        )
        if not out[-1]["nodes"]:
            del out[-1]["nodes"]
    return out


print(tree(df))
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "descr": "Tom",
        "nodes": [{"id": 5, "descr": "Eddy"}, {"id": 6, "descr": "Lisa"}],
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "descr": "Mark",
        "nodes": [
            {"id": 7, "descr": "Anna", "nodes": [{"id": 9, "descr": "Ali"}]},
            {"id": 8, "descr": "Maria"},
        ],
    },
    {"id": 4, "descr": "Tony"},
]
```

Comment: That seems to be perfect, thanks! Smart way to call the function itself in the for loop so that it stops nesting when the dataframe of the for loop is empty, thus does not have any children left over. Would never have thought of that.